# Incorrect height of Android Listview wrapped in HorizontalScrollView where list items have varying height

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, row-height

I have a ListView wrapped in a HorizontalScrollView where the list item views have different heights depending on the contents.  The list item layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nextStopType"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="P"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/dohrn_orange" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nextStopName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Customer Name"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextstopAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextStopCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/nextStopDetailsWidth"
            android:text="Stop Count"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextStopTimes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Open/Close Times"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextStopContact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextStopPieces"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/nextStopPiecesWidth"
            android:text="HUs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextStopWeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/nextStopWeightWidth"
            android:text="Weight"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

All is fine if the nextStopName is a single line, but if it wraps to two lines, the height of the list is miscalculated.  If I look at the view hierarchy in DDMS, the height of the ListView is 111 pixels, but the height of the LinearLayout enclosing the list item is 122 pixels, which is the height of the LinearLayout enclosing the nextStopType and nextStopName. The 111 is actually the height of the second LinearLayout containing the nextStopCount, et. al.

Basically, whenever a nextStopName wraps, I get this error.

Below is a screen shot where you can see the effect.

[image: Screen shot of truncated list item]
Below is the layout for this screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/nextStopAddressWidth"
                android:text="Customer Name &amp; Address"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:hint="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/nextStopDetailsWidth"
                android:text="Details"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:minWidth="@dimen/nextStopPiecesWidth"
                    android:text="HUs"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:minWidth="@dimen/nextStopWeightWidth"
                    android:text="Weight"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eolMargin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Waiting For Stops"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eolMargin"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The relevant part of the adapter is straightforward.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    }
    StopItem stopItem = getItem(position);
    TextView pdFlag = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nextStopType);
    pdFlag.setText(stopItem.getType());
    if (isCurrentDestination(stopItem)) {
        pdFlag.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        pdFlag.setTextColor(DOHRN_ORANGE);
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nextStopName);
    name.setText(stopItem.getCustomerName());

    TextView address = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nextstopAddress);
    address.setText(stopItem.getAddress());

    TextView stopCount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nextStopCount);
    stopCount.setText(stopItem.getStopCount() );

    TextView timesView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nextStopTimes);
    String times = stopItem.getTimes("\n");
    if (times.length() == 0) {
        timesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        timesView.setText(times);
    }

    TextView phoneView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nextStopContact);
    String phoneNumber = stopItem.getFormattedPhoneNumber();
    if (phoneNumber.length() == 0) {
        phoneView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        phoneView.setText(phoneNumber);
    }

    TextView pieceCount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nextStopPieces);
    pieceCount.setText(stopItem.getPieceCount());

    TextView weight = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nextStopWeight);
    weight.setText(stopItem.getWeight());
    return row;
}
```

I have tried numerous variations on the layouts, all with the same result.  The odd thing is that there are other ListViews in the app which have items with varying height and they work fine, but they are neither wrapped in a HorizontalScroll View nor have as complicated an item layout.

Comment: If you can narrow this issue down a bit, and/or post a sample project that reproduces this, I would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

You must resize `ScrollView` height with new`LayoutParams` and `requestLayout()` method in `getView()` every time when `getView()` is calling.

2 or more `AbsView` can`t hold each-other in same time, when one of them don"t have fixed size.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this.   First of all, a HorizontalScrollView is a FrameLayout and not an AbstractListView, so there are not 2 "AbsViews" in the root layout.   Are you suggesting calling requestLayout on the HorizontalScrollView inside of getView with different layout paramters, If so, what do you suggest?   I may have gotten this wrong, It might be helpful if you sketched out the code you had in mind.

Comment: More details: As stated,  it is the height of the ListVew which is incorrect.   That height is propagated to the height of the HorizontalScrollView.  Even if you calculate the height of the ListView by summing the heights of the items in the list, the calculated height is incorrect (111 pixels).  It is as if View.measure on the item is treating the item as if the nextStopName is not wrapped.  Calling requestLayout on the ListView with the correct height (122 pixels) fixes the problem, but how to get the correct item height?

Comment: Your item must have fixed size. Or your ListView hieght must be fixed.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and of course it does resolve the problem. The question is:  "Why does View.measure on TextView containing the nextStopName return the height as if the nextStopName is one line?" Yet when it comes to drawing the TextView,  it must know the width and correctly deduce that the nextStopName must be wrapped.   So the measure phase gets one answer and the drawing phase another.  How odd.  As far as this app is concerned, I will have to use 2 layouts for the list item, one for narrow screens and one for wide screens.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using different layouts for different screen sizes.  For small screens (default) the layouts use a HorizontalScrollView but the widths of the elements of the list item have a fixed width as suggested above.   For larger screens, there is no HorizontalScrollView and the list item width is the full screen and the widths of the list item elements are determined by the weights. Works like a charm.

I was led astray by suggestions that all you had to do to use a HorizontalScrollView was wrap an existing layout in a single linear layout and wrap that in a HorizontalScrollView.  The above just illustrates where such simple advice is not quite the whole story.